# How to get a Transaction with StoreKit 2 to present a refund sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storekit, in-app

I purchase a consumable product with StoreKit 2 using my device with Xcode:

```
let result = try await product.purchase()

switch result {
case .success(let verification):
    switch verification {
    case .verified(let transaction):
        await transaction.finish()    // comes here 
    ...
}
```

it is successful (I get result with verified transaction in it, my server validates the receipt).

But I can't get any transactions after it (I need it to initiate iOS 15 refund in-app flow), nothing from these works: `Transaction.currentEntitlements`, `Transaction.latest(for: productId)`, `Transaction.currentEntitlement(for: productId)` - always `nil` and `[]`. Even `Transaction.updates` doesn't emit anything.

The only mention I got is https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689480

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with storekit2 and it looks like it’s by design, at least according to this apple response on the dev forums https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687199

I haven’t looked if there is a way to do this in the original store kit api.